# WPF Button location in ToolBar

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a vertical ToolBarTray and a ToolBar with buttons. 
While most of the buttons must be in the upper part, I need one (Exit button) to be on the bottom.
But they all come one after another downwards.
Can you give me an idea on what should I do to put the last button apart from the main group, please?

Thank you!

Comment: VerticalAlignment ?

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve it with two ToolBarTrays like this:

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ToolBarTray Grid.Row="0" Background="White" IsLocked="True" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
            <ToolBar Band="1" BandIndex="1" >
                <Button Content="Cut"/>
                <Button Content="Copy"/>
                <Button Content="Paste"/>
            </ToolBar>
        </ToolBarTray>
        <ToolBarTray Grid.Row="1" Background="White" IsLocked="True" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
            <ToolBar Band="1" BandIndex="1" >
                <Button Content="Exit" />
            </ToolBar>
        </ToolBarTray>
    </Grid>
```

Then it would look like this:
[image]